# Access browser's public `window` attributes using ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri, mechanize, watir

Is it possible using Nokogiri, Mechanize or any other gem to get access to the `window` attributes that are accessible through the browser's console?

Comment: What are you trying to do, exactly?

Comment: I'm trying to build a scrapper, but I found that the site I was trying to scrape has a variable `window.productJSON` available with all the data I need. Rather than using css selectors with nokogiri, I was wondering if there was a way I could just get the data from `window.productJSON` instead

Comment: Nokogiri is just a xml/html parser. Window is a part of the JavaScript api of a browser.  No browser - no window. So what you really need is an automated browser like phantomjs or selenium.

Comment: using a headless browser or using Regex to match the json data if the you could find a pattern. and then save or parse it

Comment: No, you should look into Selenium though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need is the [Watir gem](https://github.com/watir/watir), it is actually powered by Selenium and works like magic.

It basically lets you do things like:

```
require 'watir'

browser = Watir::Browser.new

browser.goto("site-u-want-to-scrape.com")

browser.window
```

Give it a try and check out this [tutorial](https://www.rubyguides.com/2019/01/ruby-watir-gem/) to have a better understanding.

Comment: Watir worked! In order for it to output the hash to terminal I had to run `browser.execute_script "return window.productJSON"` with worked fine. Now need to figure out how to run it in a headless enviroment! :p
Thanks!

Comment: For anyone in the future who stumbles on this question, you can just do this to get Chrome in headless mode: `browser = Watir::Browser.new(:chrome, {:chromeOptions => {:args => ['--headless', '--window-size=1200x600']}})`